# Send JSON data between PHP functions

Tags: php, json

How do I get JSON data (sent by 'func2') in 'func1'?

**func1.php**

```
include 'func2.php';

$data = run_method();
```

**func2.php**

```
function run_method() {
//...
  echo json_encode(array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2));
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to `echo` but to `return` data like:

```
function run_method() {
//...
  return json_encode(array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2));
}
```

**UPD:**

To see what you get in `$data` use `var_dump($data);` after `$data = run_method();`

In `func1.php` you have to decode json_encoded data back (unserialize it).

So the best way here is not to use `json_encode` and return simple array like:

```
return array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2);
```

In your case to access `$val1` use `$data['f1']`, to access `$val2` use `$data['f2']`.

Comment: And then how can I get $val1 and $val2 in func1?

Answer (score 2):

func2.php

```
function run_method() {
 //...
  $data = json_encode(array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2));
   echo $data
   retrun $data
 }
```

func1

```
$data = run method()
```

Comment: how can I get $val1 and $val2 in func1?

Comment: echo $data['f1'] and echo $data['f2']

Comment: @UmairIqbal: You need to decode the JSON first. And your code in "func1" contains an error...

Answer (score 1):

`echo` sends your data through the webserver to the client.

To receive data from a function use `return`:

```
function run_method() {
    // Some code where you initialize $val1 and $val2
    return json_encode(array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2));
}
```

Note that you normally do not need to encode things in JSON to work with them. JSON is used when your server-side application generates some data and needs to send it to the client.

If you just need the values `$val1` and `$val2` you should to this:

```
function run_method() {
    // Some code where you initialize $val1 and $val2
    return array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2);
}
```

In `func1.php` you can access `$data` as a normal array then.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
 return json_encode(array('f1' => $val1, 'f2' => $val2));
```

insted of echo.

Comment: how can I get $val1 and $val2 in func1?